# Stack Overflow with Pathfinding Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack-overflow, path-finding

I have been working on a project that will, in short, generate a 2D matrix of numbers, with "empty" spaces are represented by 0's. Each number is connected by a list of nodes. The nodes contain the number value, the number's X and Y position, and a list of all spaces adjacent to it (its "neighbors"), with the exception of spaces diagonally adjacent to the point, due to the algorithm only allowing movements of up, down, left, and right. The issue that I am having is that, as the title would suggest, I am experiencing some stack overflow issues. I will post my code below, if anyone could help, I would be most appreciative.

```
CoordList* Puzzle::GeneratePath(CoordList* Path, int GoalX, int GoalY)
{
int CurrX;
int CurrY;

CurrX = Path->NeighborX;
CurrY = Path->NeighborY;

if(CurrX == GoalX && CurrY == GoalY)
{
    return(Path);
}
else
{
    int NewX;
    int NewY;
    double NewDistance;
    int OldX;
    int OldY;
    double OldDistance;
    CoordList* PointNeighbors = NULL;
    CoordList* BestChoice = NULL;

    for(int i = 0; i < NumDirections; i++)
    {
        CoordList* NewNeighbor = new CoordList;
        NewX = CurrX + DirectsX[i];
        NewY = CurrY + DirectsY[i];
        if(IsPossible(NewX, NewY))
        {
            NewNeighbor->NeighborX = NewX;
            NewNeighbor->NeighborY = NewY;

            if(PointNeighbors == NULL)
            {
                NewNeighbor->next = NULL;
                PointNeighbors = NewNeighbor;
            }
            else
            {
                NewNeighbor->next = PointNeighbors;
                PointNeighbors = NewNeighbor;
            }
        }
        //delete NewNeighbor;
    }

    while(PointNeighbors != NULL)
    {
        if(BestChoice == NULL)
        {

            CoordList* AChoice = new CoordList;
            AChoice->next = NULL;
            NewX = PointNeighbors->NeighborX;
            NewY = PointNeighbors->NeighborY;
            AChoice->NeighborX = NewX;
            AChoice->NeighborY = NewY;
            BestChoice = AChoice;
            PointNeighbors = PointNeighbors->next;
            //delete AChoice;
        }
        else
        {
            NewX = PointNeighbors->NeighborX;
            NewY = PointNeighbors->NeighborY;
            NewDistance = DetermineDistance(NewX, NewY, GoalX, GoalY);

            OldX = BestChoice->NeighborX;
            OldY = BestChoice->NeighborY;
            OldDistance = DetermineDistance(OldX, OldY, GoalX, GoalY);

            if(NewDistance < OldDistance)
            {
                BestChoice->NeighborX = NewX;
                BestChoice->NeighborY = NewY;
            }
            PointNeighbors = PointNeighbors->next;
        }
    }
    BestChoice->next = Path;
    Path = BestChoice;
    return(GeneratePath(Path, GoalX, GoalY));
}
}
```

I was asked to provide my determine distance function. This is just a simple implementation of the traditional Point Distance formula. Provided below.

```
double Puzzle::DetermineDistance(int OneX, int OneY, int TwoX, int TwoY)
{
int DifX;
int DifY;
double PointSum;

DifX = (TwoX - OneX);
DifY = (TwoY - OneY);
DifX = (DifX * DifX);
DifY = (DifY * DifY);
PointSum = (DifX + DifY);
return (sqrt(PointSum));
}
```

The following is the IsPossible function, which determines if an X and Y value lies within the possible grid space.

```
bool Puzzle::IsPossible(int x, int y)
{
if(x + 1 > Size - 1 || x - 1 < 0 
    || y + 1 > Size - 1 || y - 1 < 0)
{
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you check to make sure that the path cannot go onto a tile it has already tried? EDIT: I can't provide further advice unless you post the code to `DetermineDistance`. Reply to this comment when you have.

Comment: @Patashu The function has been provided. See edited question.

Comment: I do not see anything obviously wrong with your code. I recommend you attach a debugger to your code (or use a poor man's debugger, e.g., lots of printing statements) and see what loop the code gets into that makes it stack overflow. Then you'll be able to identify yourself where your code is messing up :)

Comment: @Patashu It's experiencing issues at BestChoice->next = Path. That's really all that I know. I don't have a clue as to why...

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'issues'? What happens and what do you expect to happen? Is it set to the right value, the wrong value or not set at all? What kind of 'path' does it take through the grid, does it move in the directions you expect, stop moving, move in a loop?

Comment: @patashu Well Path is passed in as a parameter. Initially it contains the start coordinates of the point, so it should never equal null. After a few recursive path finding loops, it gives an access violation error, and upon further inspection, it's trying to say that Path's top member's x and y values are -(some big number) indicating that at some point the loop set an x and y value to either below zero, or above the maximum size of the array (5 in the test case.) however, that should be impossible due to the IsPossible function, which I'll add as soon as I post this.

Comment: If the x and y values are 'some big number', then you are accessing uninitialized memory. C and C++, unlike other languages, do not set new values to 0 when you make them NOR does it stop you from accessing pointers invalid that lead to nothing all the time. I suggest that you step through your code and watch for any value becoming insanely large or negatively large - then look at how it got that value. You are probably accessing uninitialized or invalid memory to get it. Fix that. Also, I think in IsPossible it should be just x + 1 > Size not Size - 1.

Comment: The reasoning for Size - 1 is that the array that form the grid are dynamically defined to a user specified dimension. When a user enters "5" for example, a 5x5 array is formed. Since technically the first cell of an array is 0, then the largest position that a 5x5 array can hold is located at 4. Hence the Size(5) - 1. (0,5) is a position outside of the array, and thus invalid.                      However, I have noticed another odd quirk... Sometimes, seemingly without reason, the algorithm ignores the Goal, and instead traverses the grid to (0,0), oscillating between (0,0) and (0,1).

Comment: Ok, good. When it oscilates between 0,0 and 0,1, why does it go from 0,0 to 0,1? Why does it go from 0,1 to 0,0? Did it have any other possibilities? If not, why not? if it did, why aren't they picked? Now go debug ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might have a infinite recursion loop that causes the stackoverflow, as you make new local variables every recursion, especially with your observered oscillation behaviour. I assume you dont have that problem with small matrices. Its just a shot in the dark :-)

The oscillation problem indicates that you dont check whether you have already been on one place already?

Anyways, maybe you want to reconsider using another pathfinding algorithm. I would suggest a agent based solution. I used to use the following solution to solve a maze of similar structure: I started an agent with a "PositionsList" of spots where it have been, so in the beginning only with the starting point. Then it copied itself to every reachable position not being in his own PositionList, adding the new position to that list and destroying itself then. Repeat that pattern with all new agents until the first agent reaches the goal. That way you are guaranteed to find the optimal path. But it might get pretty memory heavy for big matrices, especially when there are a lot different ways to get to the goal and a lot of possible directions per position! But there are plenty of other very good pathfinding algorithms out there. Maybe one of them suits you well :-)

Good Luck!